# Export an array in .csv using

Tags: php, csv, php-5.3, export-to-csv, php-5.4

I have a problem with my .csv. So I tried to generate a .csv from an array using php. In the view I have :

```
<form id="form_logistique" action="myroute" method="post">
            <div class="form-group " style="float: left;">
                <label class="control-label" for="" style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px;">Date min</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_min" name="date_min.name" value="date_min" placeholder="Date min" class="form-control datepicker"  />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="float: left;padding-left: 20px;">
                <label class="control-label" for="" style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 20px;">Date max</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_max" name="date_max" value="{{ date_max" placeholder="Date max" class="form-control datepicker"  />
            </div>


            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-left: 20px;" value="Rechercher"></input>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-succes" style="margin-top: 25px;margin-left: 20px;" name="export" value="Exporter"></input>
    </form>
```

In php :

```
 public function getLogistique()
{
    $this->form_logistique = new Form\Form(
        new Form\Field\Text('date_min', '', true),
        new Form\Field\Text('date_max','',true),
    );
    $date_min = '';
    $date_max = '';
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPostMethod() && $this->form_logistique->bind($_POST)){
        $date_min = $this->form_logistique->date_min->getValue();
        $date_max = $this->form_logistique->date_max->getValue();
    }
    $interdit  = array(";", ",", ":", "*", "/", "|", "?", '"', "<", ">", "!", "_", "@", "[", "]", "\\", "{", "}", "~");
    $aGifts = Gain::getGiftForLogistique($date_min, $date_max, $statut);
    foreach($aGifts as $gift){
        $date = explode(' ', $gift['date_gain']);
        $gift['ref_article']        = $gift['ref_article'];
        $gift['nom']                = str_replace($interdit,"",$gift['nom']);
        $gift['prenom']             = str_replace($interdit,"",$gift['prenom']);
        $gift['pseudo']             = $gift['pseudo'];
        $gift['numero']             = trim(str_replace(";",",",str_replace("\\"," ",$gift['numero'])));
        $gift['rue']                = str_replace($interdit,"",$gift['rue']);
        $gift['complement']         = str_replace($interdit,"",$gift['complement']);
        $gift['code_postal']        = $gift['code_postal'];
        $gift['ville']              = str_replace(";",",",str_replace("\\"," ",$gift['ville']));
        $gift['pays']               = $gift['pays'];
        $gift['email']              = Gain::getEmailByIdm($gift['pseudo']);
        $gift['tel']                = str_replace(";",",",str_replace("\\"," ",$gift['tel']));
        $gift['id_instant_gagnant'] = $gift['id_instant_gagnant'];
        $gift['date_gain']          = $date[0];
        $aFilterGifts[] = $gift;
    }
    $this->aFilterGifts = $aFilterGifts;
    if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        $sFileName = 'Fichier_de_logistique.csv';
        header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
        header('Content-Type: application/download');
        fwrite($output, "sep=;\n");
        fputcsv($output, array(''Nom', 'Prenom'), ";");
        foreach ($aFilterGifts as $value) {
            fputcsv($output, $value, ";");
        }
        fpassthru($output);
        fclose($output);
    }
    return $this->render('template/customer_service/member/logistique.twig');
}
```

The .csv is generated, but the problem is that after the array in .csv I have all content .html of page and I don't understand where is the problem.Please help me! Thx in advance

Comment: Maybe because you're using `fopen('php://output', 'w')` instead of `$_POST` variables

Comment: He is writing to the output stream, this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the idea

Comment: there isn't any other html in the source you've provided....so it's coming from somewhere else and we have no way of knowing.  Some cms do print the header/footer...this could be what's happening but it's impossible to know without more details about where this is being called, ect...

Comment: I edited the question, So after my content in .csv I got and all content of .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem problem lies here:

```
if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $sFileName = 'Fichier_de_logistique.csv';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    fwrite($output, "sep=;\n");
    fputcsv($output, array('Nom', 'Prenom'), ";");
    foreach ($aFilterGifts as $value) {
        fputcsv($output, $value, ";");
    }
    fpassthru($output);
    fclose($output);
}
return $this->render('template/customer_service/member/logistique.twig');
```

The function writes headers and the content of the CSV file to STDOUT (`php://output`), but then the whole circus goes on. This function returns content of a template to it's parent function and this probably renderes it to STDOUT as well (using `echo`, `print` or something else). The easiest thing to do here (but not the correct) would be to put `die();` after `fclose($output);`:

```
if (isset($_POST['export'])) {
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $sFileName = 'Fichier_de_logistique.csv';
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    fwrite($output, "sep=;\n");
    fputcsv($output, array('Nom', 'Prenom'), ";");
    foreach ($aFilterGifts as $value) {
        fputcsv($output, $value, ";");
    }
    fpassthru($output);
    fclose($output);
    die();
}
return $this->render('template/customer_service/member/logistique.twig');
```

The correct way in my opinion is to create a new route and controller action for CSV exports, that has no HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but it may be you want to terminate the execution of the script after the fclose().

Comment: The problem is that after the array in .csv is writen the source of page

Comment: Sorry, maybe you could try rephrasing it. I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

its because at some point in the code you may have echo or print something. A better approach would be to write the csv to a file. And then send that file as Content-Disposition: attachment. Like in the code below where file is the path of file.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your idea

Answer (score 0):

fputcsv($output, array(''Nom', 'Prenom'), ";");

typo here - double single quote before Nom.